# Как во вторую активити передать значения выбарнного спинера и записать его в инт

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
Интересует такой вопрос. 
Имеется MainActivity

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bodySpiner);
     bodySelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
     Test1 = position;
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Engine.class);
     intent.putExtra("Test1", Test1);
     startActivity(intent);
 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
 }
```

В Engine.class

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 String id = i.getStringExtra("Test1");
```

Можно ли как-то передать именно int значение выбранной позиции?Просто на основании этого выбора мне надо сделать сортировку.

Comment: делайте `i.getIntExtra(Test1)` или в чем проблема?

Comment: он не дает мне вызвать непосредственно i.getIntExtra(Test1), Возможно только такgetIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue), Я вводил в defaultValue все позиции от 0 до макс кол-во позиций в моем спинере, он все равно вылетал с NPE

Comment: @Nexx ```defaultValue``` будет возвращено из метода если не будет найдено значение по переданному ключу. Приложите стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: @temqjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nexxie.diplom2/com.example.nexxie.diplom2.Engine}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2232)
                                                       at 
com.example.nexxie.diplom2.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:55)

Comment: а что за переменная `Test1` вообще? кладите в `intent` сразу `position`. Все должно работать с любым default, посмотрите проблему в другом месте. Возможно вы запускаете `intent` не в UI потоке?

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich в ней должна храниться значение int позиции, для дальнейшего сравнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете интенту `int`, а получить пытаетесь `Stirng`, воспользуйтесь методом `int getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)`

Comment: @katsoА вопрос, какое значение вводить в dtfaultValue? Я выбирал от 0 и до конца кол-ва моих позиций и всегда он ругался на NullPointerException Именно на эту строчку

Answer (score 0):

В общем, Я дурак. Я забыл что в классе Engine  я использовал RecicleView. И выводил intant после реализации RecicleView. Всем спасибо.!